# Camera Streaming - OpenCV error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Tags: python, opencv, streaming

I'm trying to stream the image of my camera ([Model](https://category.yahboom.net/products/camerakit?_pos=16&_sid=ad48c6ff9&_ss=r)) from a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Raspberry OS to my Windows 10 PC.
It works, but when I hold something white in front of the camera and the image is small, but just not enough to be sent in one package, I get the OpenCV error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Here's the python code and the console output:

Sender

```
import socket
import struct
import math
import cv2
import time
 
def main():
    
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    port = 60339
    fs = FrameSegment(s, port, "192.168.1.29")
    
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    print("Startet video capture")
    while (cap.isOpened()):
        _, frame = cap.read()
        fs.udp_frame(frame)
    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    s.close()
  
class FrameSegment(object):
    MAX_DGRAM = 2**16
    MAX_IMAGE_DGRAM = MAX_DGRAM - 64
    
    def __init__(self, sock, port, addr):
        self.s = sock
        self.port = port
        self.addr = addr
        
    def udp_frame(self, img):
    
        compress_img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1]
        dat = compress_img.tostring()
        size = len(dat)
        num_of_segments = math.ceil(size/(self.MAX_IMAGE_DGRAM))
        array_pos_start = 0
        
        while num_of_segments:
            array_pos_end = min(size, array_pos_start + self.MAX_IMAGE_DGRAM)
            self.s.sendto(
                        struct.pack("B", num_of_segments) +
                        dat[array_pos_start:array_pos_end], 
                        (self.addr, self.port)
                        )
            array_pos_start = array_pos_end
            num_of_segments -= 1
            
main()
```

Receiver

```
import numpy as np
import struct
import socket
import cv2
 
MAX_DGRAM = 2**16
index2 = False
 
def dump_buffer(s):
    """ Emptying buffer frame """
    while True:
        print("Emptying Buffer")
        seg, addr = s.recvfrom(MAX_DGRAM)
        if struct.unpack("B", seg[0:1])[0] == 1:
            print("finish emptying buffer")
            break
 
def imageReceiver():
    
    print("Socket setup")
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind(('192.168.1.29', 60339))
    dat = b''
    dump_buffer(s)
    
    while True:
        seg, addr = s.recvfrom(MAX_DGRAM)
        index = struct.unpack("B", seg[0:1])[0]
        if index > 1:
            dat += seg[1:]
        else:
            dat += seg[1:]
            img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(dat, dtype=np.uint8), 1)
            cv2.imshow('frame', img)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
            dat = b''
    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    s.close()
    
    
imageReceiver()
```

Receiver Console Output

```
Socket setup
Emptying Buffer
Emptying Buffer
finish emptying buffer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\RemoteControl.py", line 43, in <module>
    imageReceiver()
  File ".\RemoteControl.py", line 34, in imageReceiver
    cv2.imshow('frame', img)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

Comment: You need to create a window `cv2.namedWindow('frame')`

Comment: No that's not the problem. It works at the beginning, it just crashes when I make a fast mouvement. @DrBwts

Answer (score 0):

May be imshow for some reason receives an empty image.
Can you log the shape and type of img before calling imshow ?

I have run your sender and recever scripts and works perfectly.
Moveing  fast in front of my camera do not out your error.

```
    
    while True:
        seg, addr = s.recvfrom(MAX_DGRAM)
        index = struct.unpack("B", seg[0:1])[0]
    
        if index > 1:
            dat += seg[1:]
        else:
            dat += seg[1:]
            img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(dat, dtype=np.uint8), 1)

            #--- Prevent crash if img is None 
            if img is not None:
                cv2.imshow('frame', img)
            #-----------------------------------
    
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
            dat = b''
```

Comment: I found out, that it crashes only, if the image is small enough to be send in one package

Comment: Good. So now you can `pass ` or `continue`  or reshape img at right size  or not send the frame if it fit in only one package. Nice Project .

Comment: Sorry, it's if it's small but just not small enough to be sent in one package.

Comment: For the output with `print(imp.shape)` I get:
(480, 640, 3)
...
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
<class 'NoneType'>

Comment: Edited Answer. Look at  ' Prevent crash if img is None '